# зачем проверять if(fos!=null)

Tags: java, android

Учу андроид разработку. И уведел такую штуку:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.save_text);
        String text = textBox.getText().toString();

        fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {

        Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finally{
        try{
            if(fos!=null)
                fos.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){

            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Вопрос**, зачем мы проверяем (fos!=null), что если просто закрыть без проверки. ?!)

Comment: Наверное тогда будет NullPointerException.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков то есть я не могу закрыть пустой FileOuputStream ??

Comment: fos работает с каким-то ресурсом, например, файлом на диске. Если его не закрыть программно, то, даже при закрытии программы, ресурс в системе останется занятым.

Comment: @Bakhuss ну это да, а вот проверка на null для чего так и не понял

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Первоначальное значение `fos` - это null:

```
FileOutputStream fos = null;
```

Если при создании `fos`

```
fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
```

будет выброшено исключение, то в качестве значения `fos` так и останется null.
Соответственно, если в блоке `finally` (который выполнится и в случае появления исключения) не добавить проверку `fos` на null, то попытка вызвать `close` у null-a приведёт к NullPointerException, который в данном коде не отлавливается и приведёт к падению всего приложения

---

Можно заменить `catch (IOException ex)` на `catch (Exception ex)` в блоке `finally`, чтобы отлавливать и NPE, но, на мой взгляд, явная проверка лучше

---

А ещё лучше воспользоваться конструкцией [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), чтобы доверить закрытие ресурсов системе:

```
try (FileOutputStream  fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE))
{
    EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.save_text);
    String text = textBox.getText().toString();

    fos.write(text.getBytes());
    Toast.makeText(this, "Файл сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (IOException ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Единственное - в Android конструкция try-with-resources [доступна с API level 19](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/AutoCloseable)

Comment: Спасибо, понял!

Comment: по поводу try-with-resources аккуратно! оно не с 16 API а позднее (19 вроде бы). Учитывайте это.

Comment: @pavel да, спасибо, добавил в ответ